# nodejs - keep session on windows file server

Tags: node.js, file-handling, file-access

i have a problem with nodejs. I process a lot of files with nodejs. My admin has now informed me that I create hundreds of login and logoff actions on the Windows File Server within a second. He asked me to check whether this is really necessary and can possibly be minimized. I think that access to the one file always creates a new session on the Windows File Server. Is it possible to set up some kind of thread pool to keep the session active on the server?

Comment: Can you show some relevant code please?  What file operations are you doing that cause a login/logoff?  What is the Windows File Server?  Do you just mean a mounted drive?  Or a network drive?

Comment: It is about standard nodejs file actions like fs.lstatSync, fs.accessSync, fs.readdir, fs.statSync, fs.createWriteStream, fs.copyFileSync, fs.unlinkSync et cetera. The files are on a networkdrive (UNC path).

Comment: What OS are you running your node process on? How is it authenticating to the file share? (Using your credentials?)

Comment: The script runs on a Windows server and is registered as a service via a batch file. The service runs under its own domain user.